# Adding keyPressEvent to PyQT

Tags: qt, pyqt4

I have an existing PyQT code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, WindowMixin):

    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle(__appname__)
    ...
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
    def queueEvent(self, event):
```

I added the keyPressEvent:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    print "pressed"
```

It turns out that it only receive the event when I input text in some widget inside QMainWindow. When the picture has the focus, it doesn't generate the key press event. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Documentation says something about calling setFocusPolicy()  to accept focus on the widget and start receiving keyPress on the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your subwidget (picture widget) also awaits keyPressEvent and doesn't propagate it to the parent?

```
class ParentWidget(...):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print "pressed"

class ChildWidget(...):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_<Some_key>:
            ...
        # Even if the pressed key is not <Some_key>, ParentWidget won't receive this event; 
        # for sending an event to the parent you must reject it:
        else:
            event.ignore()
```